# Employees and departments database query with Sql 

Tags: sql, database, select, distinct

Suppose I have a junction table

```
EmployeeId  DeptId   
---------   ------
    1        1
    1        2
    1        3
    2        1
    2        2
    2        3   
    3        1
    3        2
    4        1
    5        2
    5        3
    6        1
    6        2
    6        3
```

So 1 employee can work in many departments

My problem is to find which employee works in multiple departments?

e.g.

If I want to search an employee who works for department `1,2,3`, the result will be: `1,2,6`

If I want to search an employee who works for department `2 & 3` the result will be `1,2,5,6`

If I want to search an employee who works for department `1 & 2` the result will be `1,2 ,3,6`

I tried with the following queries

```
a) SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeId FROM dbo.EmpDept WHERE DeptId in (2,3)
```

I got wrong result

```
b) SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeId FROM dbo.EmpDept WHERE DeptId = 2 AND  DeptId = 3
```

This time I got no records

Please help me out.

**N.B.**~ I only simulated my real time project scenario. I cannot reveal the exact schema or table names or anything related to the project as it is confidential.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this query will find all employees that work for more than 1 department.

```
select employeeid, count(*) 
from dbo.EmpDept 
group by employeeid 
having count(*) > 1;
```

if you are hoping to gather data on the employees that cross between a set of specific EmpDepts, you can utilize self joins:

```
select a.employeeid 
from dbo.EmpDept a, dbo.EmpDept b
where a.employeeid = b.employeeid 
  and a.deptid = 1
  and b.deptid = 2;
```

using this method, you will have to add another join for every new department you are looking for.

Comment: Is there any other way , to club together both the queries. One way is dynamic sql. Any other way?

Answer (score 2):

```
select employeeid
from EmpDept
where DeptId in (2,3) 
group by employeeid
having count(*) = 2
```

or

```
select employeeid
from EmpDept
where DeptId in (1,2,3) 
group by employeeid
having count(*) = 3
```

So, the count must match the number of DeptIds you are checking for. These queries assume you want to specify the DeptIds, which is what I gathered from your question.

Comment: Is there any other way , to club together both the queries. One way is dynamic sql. Any other way?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

select EmployeeId, count(*) 
from EmpDept
group by EmployeeId
having count(*) > 1;